# pygame - link an object to mouse event

Tags: android, python, pygame, mouseevent, mouse

I am trying to develop a game for Android using pygame.
It would be a platformer. To move the main charachter, I would make the game to wait for mouse events (like pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN).

In order to do that on mobile, I'd like to create a graphic representation of a joypad with arrow keys to be shown on the bottom left corner of the screen.
Now, when the user touches one of the arrows, a MOUSEBUTTONDOWN event should be triggered and the charachter should move accordingly.

My question is: since the "joypad" object is a mere draw, how can I link it to the event with pygame?
Is there a way to do so? Should I use the pixel coordinates of the arrow keys of the joypad or is there a better choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible.

When handling input, mouse input and touch input are to be handled separately.

So to answer the 2 questions you listed at the end:

- As far as I know there is no way to implement this functionality.
- You could use the pixel coordinates of the arrows. However you can use `Rect`s for that and test if the place of mouse input/touch input is inside the arrow button `Rect` with the `collidepoint` method

You can achieve that as follows:

`arrow_left.collidepoint(mouse_x, mouse_y)`

I hope this answer helped you!

Comment: Thanks, I thought like you it was not possible to treat pygame's objects with a "slot/trigger" perspective. Will test your suggestion. Anyway, aren't the mouse and touch inputs treated both with the mouse events? I am inferring so just looking at the code in [this repo](https://github.com/renpytom/rapt-pygame-example/blob/master/main.py)...

Comment: Indeed the code in that repo does treat them the same. I know that LibGDX treats them the same and I suspect that most game development libraries do.

Comment: However, from what I know, pygame does not run on Android by itself. So, if you are to make a game using pygame that runs on Android and desktop then I would think that you will basically be writing two versions of the game. One with the regular pygame library for desktop and one that uses external APIs to get it running on Android. But what do I know about this stuff? All I am saying is that pygame doesn't have touch support ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Glad to hear that I could help! Thanks for posting your question ;D